# Why won't my C# code compile with Visual Studio Code on Debian Linux?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am using a Debian Linux version of VSCode but it still should compile when I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> it compiles except there are two warnings:

> /home/hunterholly955/Snake/src/Snake.cs(14,13): warning CA1416: This
> call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Console.WindowHeight.set' is
> only supported on: 'windows'.
> [/home/hunterholly955/Snake/Snake.csproj]
>
> /home/hunterholly955/Snake/src/Snake.cs(15,13): warning CA1416: This
> call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Console.WindowWidth.set' is
> only supported on: 'windows'.
> [/home/hunterholly955/Snake/Snake.csproj]

It should still compile but it doesn't

Comment: Do you mean compile or link.  It probably compiles OK with warnings but doesn't link because there are missing calls.

Comment: `'Console.WindowHeight.set' is only supported on: 'windows'.` You're on debian. What more do you need?

Comment: Compilation with warnings are natural, so I wonder what you are looking for. If there are actual errors, edit your question to include information about them. If you aim to compile without any warning, revise your code to avoid calling Windows only APIs on Linux (with platform detection of course). Then you can suppress such warnings with confidence.